# Passing functions with arguments in Stylus

Tags: css, function, stylus

I keep trying to pass functions as arguments in Stylus, but it never renders anything. What am I doing wrong? I don't understand this...

```
foo(fn)
    fn(x)
fn(x)
    background x
.myclass
    foo(black)
```

I'd expect this to render a black background for .myclass.

Stylus' site is currently down so here's the [cached link to the relevant doc](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.html&aq=f&oq=cache%3ahttp://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.html&aqs=chrome.0.57j58.2652j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I screwed that up pretty bad (it's early). For others curious, you need to pass in variables like so:

```
foo(fn, x)
    fn(x)
bg(bg_color)
    background bg_color
.myclass
    foo(bg, black)
```